# Custom merge of binary files in SVN

Tags: svn

I have a problem of that our app is managing a lot of binary files. I would like to switch to SVN so multiple people may edit the thing over the net. These files can be modified by two parts and we are able to implement diff/merge functionality for them. Is it possible in SVN to substitute the diff/patch application for a file type (or overall)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can [use external differencing and merge tools](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html) with SVN.

Note: if you are not too committed to SVN already, you could consider other tools such as Git, in which case you can also use external tools, see the `--tool` option of [git-difftool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) and [git-mergetool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool).